# Ramsey Upper Bound improvement

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I am trying to understand the upper bound that David Conlon produced for the diagonal Ramsey Numbers

$$R(n+1,n+1) \leq n^{-c \frac { log n}{log \;{log n}}} \binom {2n}{n}$$

With the binomial theorem it is shown that

$$R(n+1,n+1) \leq \frac{4^n} {\sqrt {\pi n}}$$

which is not difficult to understand. I'm having a hard time trying to understand the term

$$n^{-c \frac { log n}{log \;{log n}}}$$

and how big of an improvement it is.